# Access wordpress pages using a self signed shared ssl

Tags: pages, facebook, ssl, https

I am trying to access a wordpress page to use in a Facebook tab. I have a self signed ssl installed and I only get a server 404 error page.

I am using the wordpress https plugin, but I am not having any luck.

I set the individual page here to force https  https://mypastaspot.com/facebook/

I've tried getting to the page via ip `https://192.254.194.11/~mypastas/facebook/`

If i browse to `https://192.254.194.11/~mypastas` the site sort of loads, but is missing styles and throws a wordpress 404.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Which plugin precisely? How exactly are you using the certificate?

Comment: The plug is Wordpress HTTPS.
I'm not sure what you mean how am I using the certificate. Really I'm looking for a way to have one certificate to use on a shared ip. I only need this to get past facebooks secure page requirement. No sensitive info is being captured.